# Succinic anhydride esterification won't go forward

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, catalysis, reaction-control, esters

I'm trying to react succinic anhydride with a decyl alcohol to produce mono-decyl succinate. Literature and Google searches suggest that the monoesterification should proceed without catalyst. However I'm failing to get the reactions going. Reactions were in reflux, $\pu{80-140 ^\circ C}$ at $\pu{1 atm}$.

Any suggestions if anhydride esterifications even needs a catalyst? Would a solvent help?

Comment: Addition of catalytic pyridine should assist it.

Comment: Do you use solvent? if so, what is it? Would you please include those in your question?

Answer (score 3):

The monoesters of succinic acid can be prepared using Steglich esterification method (Ref.1,2), which is specially suitable for alcohols with the $\ce{OH}$ functional group is in steric hindrance. In this method, dicyclohexylcarbodiimide (DCC) as the coupling reagent and 4-dimethylaminopyridine (DMAP) as a catalyst are used. The reference 1 gave a typical procedure as follows:

> To a stirred solution of 10mmol carboxylic acid in $\pu{lO ml}$ anhydrous $\ce{CH2Cl2}$ (in the case of sparingly soluble acids, in DMF) is added $\pu{30-110 mg}$ DMAP and $\pu{20-40 mmol}$ alcohol or thiol ($\pu{10 mmol}$ with alcohols or thiols which are not easily removable without significant loss; $\pu{3.4 mmol}$ with glycerol). DCC is added to the reaction mixture at OT, which is then stirred for $\pu{5 min}$ at $\pu{0 ^\circ C}$ and $\pu{3 h}$ at $\pu{20 ^\circ C}$. Precipitated urea is then filtered off and the filtrate evaporated down *in vacuo*. The residue is taken up in $\ce{CH2Cl2}$ and, if necessary, filtered free of any further precipitated urea. The $\ce{CH2Cl2}$ solution is washed twice with $\pu{0.5 N}$ $\ce{HCl}$ and with saturated $\ce{NaHCO3}$ solution, and then dried over $\ce{MgSO4}$. The solvent is removed by evaporation and the ester isolated by distillation or recrystallization. Crystalline products can be obtained in pure form by filtration on a short silica gel column (eluent: $\ce{CH2Cl2}$ or $\ce{CHCl3}$).

For example, recently, this method has successfully used to couple Vitamin $\mathrm{D_2}$ to succinic anhydride in order to achieve succinic monoester of Vitamin $\mathrm{D_2}$ (Ref.3). However, there is an US patent publication revealing cheap solvent free method using alkali salt bases such as $\ce{NaOAc, KOAc, Na2CO3}$, and $\ce{K2CO3}$ as catalysts to efficiently prepare mono alkyl esters from cyclic anhydrides (Ref.4).

**References:**

1. Bernhard Neises, Wolfgang Steglich, "Simple Method for the Esterification of Carboxylic Acids," *Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.* **1978**, *17(7)*, 522–524 (https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.197805221)([PDF](https://www.thevespiary.org/rhodium/Rhodium/Vespiary/talk/files/6345-Simple-Method-for-the-Esterification-of-Carboxylic-Acids2a74.pdf)).
2. Gerhard Höfle,  Wolfgang Steglich,  Helmut Vorbrüggen, "4‐Dialkylaminopyridines as Highly Active Acylation Catalysts. [New synthetic method (25)]," *Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.* **1978**, *17(8)*, 569-583 (https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.197805691).
3. Victar Nyaarugwe, "Synthesis and Characterization of Hybrid Compounds for the Treatment of Bone Related Diseases," *Journal of Trauma and Orthopedic Nursing* **2018**, *2(1:4)*, 16 pages ([PDF](https://www.imedpub.com/articles/synthesis-and-characterization-of-hybridcompounds-for-the-treatment-of-bonerelated-diseases.pdf)).
4. Mark, B. Erman, Joe W. Snow, Mikhail Y. Lebedev, "Process for making monomenthyl esters," *US Patent* **2007**, US 7,247,743 B1 ([PDF](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/e9/5b/ef/b73d67f4602353/US7247743.pdf)).